# CoreData sort by factor of date

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an iOS app that frequently adds content and saves it in CoreData. Each content item has a fixed score.

I would like to be able to sort these in a similar way to the Hacker News algorithm (http://amix.dk/blog/post/19574). That is, against a calculated attribute based partly on the age of the content, partly on the score of the content; e.g. (score) / (age in hours)^(1.8)

With plain SQL this is possible, but does CoreData abstract things too much?

Comment: Have you tried and found a problem? How have you thought of doing it? Do you mean 'can I do all the calculation in the fetch'?

Comment: Yes, sorry - is it possible to do the calculation in the fetch and sort by the result?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new property the contains your calculated score.

When you update your object, undated the calculated score as well.

If you want to apply a sort to a fetch request, using the calculated score as a sort key, **don't** add it as a transient property as these aren't stored in the underlying SQL database.

Comment: I have an attribute that contains the base score for the content item. At "fetch-time" I need to do the calculation - I don't think I can perform the calculation at any other time as it's the age of the item that's important. Once created, the objects don't get updated.

Comment: How many items are we talking? If it's not too many, could you update all the objects (calcScore = score/age^1.8) and then do another fetch, sorting by calcScore? If you're talking a small number (say < 1000) and you do it on a background thread you should be able to do it without affecting the UI.